# Is it ok to post short how-tows on DA?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it bad form to ask questions about problems I don't have?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/is-it-bad-form-to-ask-questions-about-problems-i-dont-have)

A lot of Drupalers have their own blog where they share their how-tos and trips. I have a few to share as well but don't want to setup and maintain my own blog.

Is it ok to post them on DA? For example, I want to show how I replaced basic OG functionality with flags and node reference (including links to posts that helped me get there).

Comment: Please, create a blog — subscribing is not so good on Stackoverflow :(

Comment: @kalabro Actually you can subscribe to any user's questions/answers as an RSS feed (the link is at the bottom of each profile page)

Comment: I would suggest to wait a day, or two, before writing your own answer; this is not required, but users will feel free to writing their own answers. You could also get interesting answers you didn't think of before.

Comment: @kiamlaluno +1. Wait a day, or two, before writing your own answer, is the better way if you're planning to add a howto.

Comment: I have merged this question with the existing one that is part of the FAQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, please do :)

Asking questions that you already know the answer to is fine, in fact it's encouraged (I'm quoting [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) here).

As long as the post is phrased in the style of a question (e.g. How can I recreate Organic Groups on a more basic scale?), and is on-topic/useful to the site (which I'm sure that particular question would be), then it would be a valuable addition to the site.

You never know, you might even get an answer from someone else in the community who's solved the same problem in a simpler way. Everyone wins really!

**EDIT**

Also see [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to), in which the fabled Jeff Atwood himself encourages people to do this. I think this second question is actually a far better example, the OP is basically asking the same question that you have, just not about Drupal in particular.