# Is it fine to post a question even if we already found the answer?

Tags: discussion

Sometime, a problem we are trying to solve and want to post on Drupal Answer is resolved before we post it.

Sometimes, I think the question is worth being post, due to the nature of the problem.

Is it OK to post the question in such case?

**Update:**
There is another question with similar subject, i.e. "[Is it ok to post short how-tows on DA?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/872)". I think that question is somewhat different as it is talk about generating question and answer from tutorial/learning. But the answer to that question can be perfectly applied to this question also.

Comment: This question seems like a variation of [this one](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/872), no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, Yes it looks like both question are same, but there is slight difference. The linked question is asking about the already available literature/tutorial and posting it in the form of Q&A. This question I asked, that sometime I was looking for answer and before posting I get a answer. So this is the case of on the spot generation of Q&A while previous one was from generating Q&A from tutorial. NOW, the answer which was mentioned in your provided link is I think perfectly applicable here also. So, I think that answer we can apply to this question also.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question could be the same answer mentioned in the question "[Is it ok to post short how-tows on DA?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/872)".

Although any input is appreciated.