# Is this question too similar to another to ask? How should I handle a situation like this?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question: [How to check if an entity bundle has a field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260536/how-to-check-if-an-entity-bundle-has-a-field), but soon realized there was another very similar question: [Get all fields defined in a bundle](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/get-all-fields-defined-in-a-bundle). I ended up answering my own question, referencing the other, but added additional steps to check that a specific field existed vs just getting a list of all fields. Was this the correct way to go? Should I have deleted my question instead? What's really giving me pause is that I  would not have asked the question to begin with if I had found the linked question / answer before I asked.

[The answer](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/60/48114) for [Is it bad form to ask questions about problems I don't have?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/is-it-bad-form-to-ask-questions-about-problems-i-dont-have) seems to indicate that I've handled this situation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it bad form to ask questions about problems I don't have?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/is-it-bad-form-to-ask-questions-about-problems-i-dont-have) is answering about those problems resolved before asking any question, not asking a question that has been already asked or is very close to another question.
In short that question is asking *I resolved many problems when developing Drupal code, and I think that some of them could be helpful to other users with the same problem. Is it fine if I post a question for a problem I resolved to which I add an answer to share what I did?*

Don't take that answer as suggestion that asking a question that has been already answered is perfectly fine to do in any case.